# How to pass safe args as bundle in android explicit deep link?

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack-navigation, android-deep-link

I am creating an explicit deep link in navigation component using safe args.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = new NavDeepLinkBuilder(getApplicationContext())
                .setGraph(R.navigation.mobile_navigation)
                .setDestination(R.id.nav_order_details)
                .setArguments(//TODO pass bundle)
                .setComponentName(MainActivity.class)
                .createPendingIntent();
```

The problem is I need to pass a bundle in arguments but I dont know how to convert Safe args to bundle in java.

I found this format in kotlin

```
OrderDetailsFragmentArgs(id).toBundle()
```

I need to convert it into java code. Please help.

Comment: Why are you using jetpack navigation in java? Jetpack components are not intended to use in java.

Comment: @ʀᴀʜɪʟ That is wrong. Only the `-ktx` Jetpack libraries and Compose are not intended for use in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it by using this code

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("orderId", id);

OrderDetailsFragmentArgs args = OrderDetailsFragmentArgs.fromBundle(bundle);

PendingIntent intent = new NavDeepLinkBuilder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setGraph(R.navigation.mobile_navigation)
                    .setDestination(R.id.nav_order_details)
                    .setArguments(args.toBundle())
                    .setComponentName(MainActivity.class)
                    .createPendingIntent();
```